# Connect .Net console application in Visual Studio to my Salesforce org and access the Salesforce data

Tags: .net, salesforce

I want to access the Salesforce CRM data using .Net console application. I tried doing it but I am getting errors related to salesforce authentication.

When I am trying to Generate WSDL file, I am unable to do so and its saying that I have insufficient permissions. When I try to use Rest Api, I am unable to get the Access_token and Instance_Url. So, please suggest where I am possibly going wrong..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.